# Invalid response using https module in javaScript to fetch a public facebook profile

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, https

I am using node's `https` module to fetch my public profile from facebook. But i am getting 302 status code in response. Following is the code i am using:

```
var https = require('https');

var options = {
    hostname: 'www.facebook.com',
    path: '/suri.nik',
    method: 'GET'
};
var results = '';
var req = https.request(options, function (res) {

    console.log('STATUS CODE : ' + res.statusCode);

    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        results = results + chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function () {
        console.log(results);
    });
    res.on('error', function () {
        console.log('error here');
    });
});

req.on('error', function (e) {
    console.log('error in ur request: ' + e);
});


req.end();
```

I am getting STATUS CODE : 302, i should be getting status code : 200 with valid html in response of my profile. I am able to fetch the public profile from my browser or postman using the same link(`www.facebook.com/suri.nik`) Where lies the issue? is it the way i am making my request?

Comment: You getting 302 because Facebook say the URL have moved. And Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. Use the API.

Comment: @WizKid, thanks for the response.But i can not access the public profile of another user using API. since, i want to access the public profile of another users i have to replicate the browser request. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Doesn't matter what you can or not can do. https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php doesn't allow you to scrape